# Does boost::multiprecision::mpz_int constructor copy the mpz_t?

Tags: c++, boost, gmp

I am using boost multiprecision with the gmp backend. Consider the following code to construct a multiprecision number from a binary representation:

```
typedef boost::multiprecision::mpz_int BigInt;

BigInt createNumber(const unsigned char* in, size_t length)
{
    mpz_t number;
    mpz_init2(number, length);
    mpz_import(number, 1, 1, length, 1, 0, in);
    BigInt id(number);
    mpz_clear(number);
    return number;
}
```

I was under the impression that the call to `mpz_clear(number)´ is required to not leak the`mpz_t`, because the`boost::multiprecision::mpz_int`constructor copies the value of the`mpz_t` and therefore takes no ownership of it. By using the debugger I figured out that this constructor is called:

```
gmp_int(const mpz_t val)
{
    mpz_init_set(this->m_data, val);
}
```

This seems to confirm my suspicion since [mpz_init_set](https://gmplib.org/manual/Simultaneous-Integer-Init-_0026-Assign.html#Simultaneous-Integer-Init-_0026-Assign) initializes the internal `mpz_t` variable with the value of the operand instead of just copying the `mpz_t`.

But when I do the `mpz_clear(number)`to free the memory I get wrong values for the constructed `BigInt`. Removing the `mpz_clear(number)` yields the correct result. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after crafting this answer and looking at the code I saw the mistake. I was returning the `number` when I should be returning the `id`. This is why conversion constructors should be explicit :)

So yes the constructor does copy the mpz_int. But I was freeing it before it could be copied (on function return). In addition I leaked one mpz_t every time.